# Generating entity id with easily distinguished types/groups

Tags: javascript, python, postgresql, redis, uniqueidentifier

I need to generate unique id in distributed environment. Catch is that each id has to have a group/type information that can be examined by simple script.

Details:
I have some, fixed, number of entity types (lets call them: message, resource, user, session, etc). I need to generate unique id in form:  so i can know where to direct request based only on id - without db, list, or anything.

I have considered uuid in version 3 or 5 but as far as I can see it is impossible to know "namespace" provided for generating id.

I have also considered just replacing first x characters of uuid with fixed values but then i will lose uniqueness.

I have also considered Twitter snowflake or Instagram way of generating id's but I don't know the number of nodes in each group and I cannot assume anything.

I will be using them in JS, Python, Redis and Postgresql so portability of code (and representation - big integer representation is full of bugs in JavaScript) is required. So either pure "number" or string that can be formatted as uuid (binary representation) for database.

edit:

I will generate them in Python or in Postgresql and only pass them in JavaScript and Redis.

Comment: You could use version 4 — you get 122 bits where you can encode whatever you like using whatever scheme you need.

Comment: Why do you use uniqueness when you add x character before/after the uuid?

Comment: @arkocal: if I add characters before or after then uuid is no longer and uuid - it will not fit in to postgresql uuid data type and I will lose optimisations from that.

Comment: @lanzz I thought about it but this solution is also problematic - I would have to ensure that the appropriate uniqueness is guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following format for generating a UUID in version 4:

```
XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-4PPP-SPTT-TTTT TTTT TTTT
```

where the meanings of the letters are as follows:

- `X` - namespace;
- `Y`, `Z`, `P` - id of the aplication, server pool and storage node;
- `S` - one of the values: `8`,`9`,`A`,`B` chosen at random;
- `T` - shifted timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

UUID version 4 is basically 122 random bits + 4 bits for UUID version + 2 bits reserved. Its uniqueness relies on low probability of generating the same 122 bits.

UUID version 5 is basically 122 hash bits + 4 bits for UUID version + 2 bits reserved. Its uniquess relies on low probability of collision for 122-bit truncated SHA1 hash.

When you replace N bits of UUID (as long as they are not "version" or "reserved" bits), you make a tradeoff: probability of collision becomes higher 2^N times.

For example, if you use UUID4, probability of collision is neglectible, namely 2^122. In the same time, if you have up to 8 entity types and use UUID4 with 8 bits replaced, probability of collision becomes 2^194, which is bigger, though still neglectible.

So probably using UUID4 with N bits replaced may be a safe option without taking extra care to guarantee uniquess.